# Автоматическая обработка двух полей при смене радио батона

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qradiobutton

На *PyQt5* есть интерфейс: **2** текстовых поля (`field_one` и `field_two`), рядом с каждым размещено **3** радиобатона (`rb_one_btn1`, `rb_one_btn2`, `rb_one_btn3`, где **`one`** меняется на **`two`** для второго поля), объединенных в 2 группы(`btn_group_one` и `btn_group_two`). 
При смене кнопки текст автоматически считывается из текстового поля и передается в одну из функций.

Вот такой код есть для первого текстового поля

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, uic
import sys

class String():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.string = text

    def btn1_btn2(self):
        return f'From 1 to 2: {self.string}'
    def btn2_btn1(self):
        return f'From 2 to 1: {self.string}'
    def btn1_btn3(self):
        return f'From 1 to 3: {self.string}'
    def btn3_btn1(self):
        return f'From 3 to 1: {self.string}'
    def btn2_btn3(self):
        return f'From 2 to 3: {self.string}'
    def btn3_btn2(self):
        return f'From 3 to 2: {self.string}'


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi("two_fields.ui", self)

        self.variants = {"BTN1-BTN2": String.btn1_btn2, "BTN2-BTN1": String.btn2_btn1, "BTN1-BTN3": String.btn1_btn3, "BTN3-BTN1": String.btn3_btn1, "BTN2-BTN3": String.btn2_btn3, "BTN3-BTN2": String.btn3_btn2}

        self.btn_group_one.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button)

        self.old = 'BTN1'
        self.new = None

    def check_button(self, button):
        if self.old != button.text():
            self.new = button.text()
            self.convert(self.old, self.new)
            self.old = self.new

    def convert(self, mode_from, mode_to):
        self.string = String(self.field_one.toPlainText())
        self.mode = f'{mode_from}-{mode_to}'
        self.result = self.variants.get(self.mode)(self.string)
        self.field_one.setText(self.result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Код **.ui** файла разместил на [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/cEm2SzRi), чтобы здесь не засорять.

В таком случае все работает:

[image: Рабочее окно для одного поля]

Но есть сложность в реализации такого поведения одновременно для **2** полей, т.е чтобы можно было взаимодействовать с полями по разному и по отдельности, вот так:

[image: Ожидаемое поведение]

Возможно следует добавить словарь с начальным состоянием кнопок для каждого поля, например:

```
self.checked_one = {'old': 'BTN1', 'new': None}
self.checked_two = {'old': 'BTN1', 'new': None}
self.btn_group_one.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button, доп_параметры)
self.btn_group_two.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button, доп_параметры)
```

Но тогда надо расширить функционал, так чтобы методы `check_button` и `convert` принимали дополнительные параметры, например так:

```
def check_button(self, button, checked, field): # ???
    if checked['old'] != button.text():
        checked['new'] = button.text()
        convert(checked['old'], checked['new'], field)
        checked['old'] = checked['new']

def convert(self, mode_from, mode_to, field_from_to):
    self.field = field_from_to #???
    self.string = String(self.field.toPlainText())
    self.mode = f'{mode_from}-{mode_to}'
    self.result = self.variants.get(self.mode)(self.string) # ???
    self.field.setText(self.result)
```

Т.е. в итоге должно передаваться, что-то наподобие `self.btn_group_one.buttonClicked.connect(self.check_button(???, self.checked_one, 'field_one'))`

Но я же не могу повесить на `connect` метод с доп. параметрами, тогда возникают ошибки.

Как можно реализовать возможность обработки **2** полей независимо? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все ваши рассуждения правильные. Я лишь приведу возможную реализацию ваших рассуждений:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets, uic


class String():
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.string = text

    def btn1_btn2(self):
        return 'From 1 to 2: {}'.format(self.string)
    def btn2_btn1(self):
        return 'From 2 to 1: {}'.format(self.string)
    def btn1_btn3(self):
        return 'From 1 to 3: {}'.format(self.string)
    def btn3_btn1(self):
        return 'From 3 to 1: {}'.format(self.string)
    def btn2_btn3(self):
        return 'From 2 to 3: {}'.format(self.string)
    def btn3_btn2(self):
        return 'From 3 to 2: {}'.format(self.string)


class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        uic.loadUi("two_fields.ui", self)

        self.variants = {"BTN1-BTN2": String.btn1_btn2, 
                         "BTN2-BTN1": String.btn2_btn1, 
                         "BTN1-BTN3": String.btn1_btn3, 
                         "BTN3-BTN1": String.btn3_btn1, 
                         "BTN2-BTN3": String.btn2_btn3, 
                         "BTN3-BTN2": String.btn3_btn2}

        self.btn_group_one.buttonClicked.connect(
                    lambda btn: self.check_button(btn, "one"))     # + "one"
        self.btn_group_two.buttonClicked.connect(                  # +++
                    lambda btn: self.check_button(btn, "two"))        

        self.old = self.old_2 = 'BTN1'                             # + self.old_2
        self.new = self.new_2 = None                               # + self.new_2

    def check_button(self, button, group):                         # + group
        if group=="one" and self.old != button.text():             # +  group=="one" and
            self.new = button.text()
            self.convert(self.old, self.new, group)                # + group
            self.old = self.new
        elif group=="two" and self.old_2 != button.text():         # +++
            self.new_2 = button.text()
            self.convert(self.old_2, self.new_2, group)      
            self.old_2 = self.new_2

    def convert(self, mode_from, mode_to, group):                   # + group
        if group=="one":                                            # +
            self.string = String(self.field_one.toPlainText())
            self.mode = '{}-{}'.format(mode_from, mode_to)
            self.result = self.variants.get(self.mode)(self.string)
            self.field_one.setText(self.result)
        elif group=="two":                                          # +++
            self.string = String(self.field_two.toPlainText())
            self.mode = '{}-{}'.format(mode_from, mode_to)
            self.result = self.variants.get(self.mode)(self.string)
            self.field_two.setText(self.result)            


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]